# Openvpn server conf route

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

Here is my openvpn server conf -

```
server 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0
verb 3
key /etc/openvpn/pki/private/VPN.SERVERNAME.COM.key
ca /etc/openvpn/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/pki/issued/VPN.SERVERNAME.COM.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/pki/dh.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pki/ta.key
key-direction 0
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun

proto udp
# Rely on Docker to do port mapping, internally always 1194
port 1194
dev tun0
status /tmp/openvpn-status.log

user nobody
group nogroup

### Route Configurations Below
route 192.168.254.0 255.255.255.0
```

I'm trying to understand what does the "route" configuration do? I checked the ip addr of the host where my openvpn is running but its ip address is different.

Answer (score 1):

Push routes to the client to allow it
to reach other private subnets behind
the server.  Remember that these
private subnets will also need
to know to route the OpenVPN client.

```
route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
```

Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet
for OpenVPN to draw client addresses from.
The server will take `10.8.0.1` for itself,
the rest will be made available to clients.
Each client will be able to reach the server
on `10.8.0.1`.

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
```